# How to get at a relationship items properties in Core Data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, ios, nsarray

Say you have a Core Data object called Workshop. It has a to-many relationship to a Student object.

How would I create an NSArray of the students within the Workshop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a NSSet opposed to an array, as they are unordered.

> Use mutableSetValueForKey: This
>   returns a proxy that mutates the
>   relationship and does KVO
>   notifications. Think of the name as
>   "[NS]MutableSet" "valueForKey" rather
>   than "mutableSetValue" "forKey",
>   because it returns a mutable set that
>   you manipulate
>
> ```
> NSMutableSet *Students;
> Students = [Workshop mutableSetValueForKey: @"Students"];
> [Students addObject: newStudent];
> [Students removeObject: oldStudent];
> ```

[source](http://borkware.com/quickies/single?id=249)

Answer (score 2):

These relationships are normally declared as an `NSSet` in your NSManagedObject subclass, like this:

```
@property (retain) NSSet* students;
```

And there's also some special accessor methods:

```
- (void)addStudentsObject:(NSManagedObject *)value;
- (void)removeStudentsObject:(NSManagedObject *)value;
- (void)addStudents:(NSSet *)value;
- (void)removeStudents:(NSSet *)value;
```

NSSets are similar to NSArrays, but they are not ordered, since Core Data does not guarantee a special sort order for managed objects.

Answer (score 1):

You usually have no need to create an array of a to-many relationship because they automatically come in a NSSet anyway. This gives better flexibility than an array.

However, if you need students sorted in a particular order you can use a sort descriptor to return a sorted array. Suppose you already have the WorkShop instances and you wanted an array of students sorted by last name in descending order, you would use this:

```
WorkShop *aWorkShop=//... fetch the appropiate WorkShop instances
NSSortDescriptor *sort=[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"lastName" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortedStudents=[aWorkShop.students sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
```