# Core Data Inverse Relationship Not Being Set

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode4, entity-relationship, inverse

I've got two Entities that I'll call A and B.   They are configured with To-Many relationships in both directions, so A.myBs and B.myAs are both NSSets.

Here is my bizarre problem.

When I add a B to my A entity, I do it using the mutableSetValueForKey like this:

```
NSMutableSet *myBSet = [myA mutableSetValueForKey:@"myBs"];
[myBSet addObject:theBtoAdd];
```

This does add the theBtoAdd to the A entity but does not add the inverse relationship.   Core Data context save doesn't kick any errors, but my A object doesn't have the B inverse set.  If I exit the application, even the partial relationship isn't saved.

Here's the strange part... if I just switch my code around and do the opposite (there are reasons why this is harder to do for my particular application) - add A to B instead of adding B to A like this:

```
NSMutableSet *myASet = [myB mutableSetValueForKey:@"myAs"];
[myASet addObject:theAtoAdd];
```

It works just fine.   By the way, I have plenty of other to-many relationships that work.   Just this one doesn't.

Couple of other things:
1) My core data object model looks good, but this is the first new entity that I've added under Xcode 4
2) I've check, rechecked and gone blind looking at my custom NSManagedObjects, but they look fine - declared dynamic, NSSet, no conflicting setters/getters... etc.

Any help or debugging suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I'm stuck with the same problem :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just had the same problem, which was why I saw this question. Maybe my solution will help some people in the same situation.

For me the answer was that in the NSManagedObject subclass I had over-riden:

```
- (void)willChangeValueForKey:(NSString *)inKey withSetMutation:(NSKeyValueSetMutationKind)inMutationKind usingObjects:(NSSet *)inObjects

- (void)didChangeValueForKey:(NSString *)inKey withSetMutation:(NSKeyValueSetMutationKind)inMutationKind usingObjects:(NSSet *)inObjects
```

This prevents the correct notifications being sent to the parent class (NSManagedObject) which  handles the automatic reverse relationships.

Comment: This helped me also. Remember to do the same also for -(void)didChangeValueForKey:(NSString *)key; (plain values)

Comment: Suuuch a dumb bug in my codebase, but this answer pointed out where the problem would be, so you've got my upvote. Thank you sir.

Comment: Just to be clear.  You can override them but you have to call super.  I do it first thing.  In Swift
     
    `super.didChangeValue(forKey: key)
      OR  
     super.didChangeValue(forKey: inKey, withSetMutation: inMutationKind, using: inObjects)

Answer (score 3):

I found the error, if you are overriding any of these methods

```
// KVO change notification
- (void)willChangeValueForKey:(NSString *)key;
- (void)didChangeValueForKey:(NSString *)key;
- (void)willChangeValueForKey:(NSString *)inKey withSetMutation:(NSKeyValueSetMutationKind)inMutationKind usingObjects:(NSSet *)inObjects;
- (void)didChangeValueForKey:(NSString *)inKey withSetMutation:(NSKeyValueSetMutationKind)inMutationKind usingObjects:(NSSet *)inObjects;
```

it will cause NSManagedObject don't work well and the relationships won't be set correctly

Apple documentation: *You must not override these methods.*

Answer (score 0):

If you're subclassing the Managed Object, shouldn't there be auto-generated to-many relationship methods?  So that you would just need to call:

```
[aObject addBObject:bObject];
```

Comment: Yes, I can and did try that with the same result.  I'm specifically following the advice in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206788/how-to-get-at-a-relationship-items-properties-in-core-data and using the mutableSetValueForKey.