# Core Data does not save one-to-many relationship

Tags: ios, macos, core-data

I have two entities, `Document` and `Attachment`. A document can have many attachments. An attachment can belong to a single document.

For some reason, Core Data is not saving the relationship between a document and its attachments when I do the following:

```
[document addAttachments:attachments];
[context save:&error];
[context reset];
```

If I fetch the document after executing the above code, its attachments will be empty. Yet, the attachments are saved.

The relationship **is** saved if I set the inverse relationship manually:

```
[document addAttachments:attachments];
for (Attachment *attachment in attachment)
{
    attachment.document = document;
}
[context save:&error];
[context reset];
```

I thought it wasn't necessary to set a relationship both ways with Core Data. What am I doing wrong?

In case it helps, the relationships are defined as follows:

**attachments**

- Transient: NO
- Optional: YES
- Destination: Attachment
- Inverse: document
- Delete Rule: Cascade
- Type: To Many
- Ordered: NO

**document**

- Transient: NO
- Optional: YES
- Destination: Document
- Inverse: attachments
- Delete Rule: Nullify
- Type: To One

### Also tried

- Using `mutableSetValueForKey:` instead of the generated accessor.
- Adding the attachments one by one.
- Retaining the `attachments` array, just in case.

Same result.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Were you ever able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Maybe these two answers might help [Core Data Inverse Relationship Not Being Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191160/core-data-inverse-relationship-not-being-set)

[How to get at a relationship items properties in Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206788/how-to-get-at-a-relationship-items-properties-in-core-data)

Can you post some code?

Comment: Thanks @aniruddhc. I'm not overriding `willChangeValueForKey:withSetMutation:inMutationKind:usingObjects:` or `didChangeValueForKey:withSetMutation:inMutationKind:usingObjects:`. What part of the code would be useful?